# why both exports and module.exports used in main module of express (express.js file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

i read [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js/7142924) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992836/error-while-using-both-module-exports-and-exports), and other internet searches. the summery of my search is `module.exports` and `exports` point to same object that will be exported and those exports are accessible with `require(<package identifier> or <JS file identifire>).`
because the parameter passing strategy in the `JS` is `call-by-sharing` if we assign a function to `module.exports` the `exports` object is now useless.(because that `exports` still pointing to previous value of `module.exports`)
i add this too from  `nodejs.com`, `require()` function will give us exported variables and functions from `main module` of a `package` or a normal `js` file.

now the question is why in [express.js file](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js) we have other things that are attached to exports while we assigned a function to `module.exports`?

Answer (score 0):

because in this line

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;
```

these are pointing to same function and in `js` function are objects .